# transform table laravel row to column based on item

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, pivot

hi please help i have table like this :

```
po          date        bmi_code    qty
6800083953  2020-08-12  TA23D7GANV6 2198.27
6800083953  2020-08-12  TA40Y3LANC2 394.98
6800083953  2020-08-13  TA23D7GANV6 650.74
6800083953  2020-08-13  TA40Y3LANC2 626.52
6800083952  2020-08-14  TA23D7GANV6 424.944
6800083953  2020-08-14  TA40Y3LANC2 626.52
```

and i want data like this,
how to that,

```
bmi_code    2020-08-12  2020-08-13  2020-08-14  
TA23D7GANV6 2198.27     650.74      424.944
TA40Y3LANC2 394.98      626.52      626.52
```

and this my code

```
$itemlist= ProductionOutput::select('bmi_code',function($query){
        $query->DB::raw('SUM(qty) as qty')->groupBy('date');
    })->groupBy('bmi_code')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform pivot transformation of your data first you will need to query the records grouped by `bmi_code` and `date`

```
$productionResults = ProductionOutput::select('bmi_code','date',DB::raw('SUM(qty) as qty'))
    ->groupBy(['bmi_code','date'])
    ->get();
```

`$productionResults` will have data probably like

```
[
    ['bmi_code' => 'TA23D7GANV6', 'date' => '2020-08-12', 'qty'=> 2198.27],
    ['bmi_code' => 'TA23D7GANV6', 'date' => '2020-08-13', 'qty'=> 650.74],
    ['bmi_code' => 'TA23D7GANV6', 'date' => '2020-08-14', 'qty'=> 424.944],
    ['bmi_code' => 'TA40Y3LANC2', 'date' => '2020-08-12', 'qty'=> 394.98],
    ['bmi_code' => 'TA40Y3LANC2', 'date' => '2020-08-13', 'qty'=> 626.52],
    ['bmi_code' => 'TA40Y3LANC2', 'date' => '2020-08-14', 'qty'=> 626.52],

]
```

Here we will add arrays for each distinct `bmi_code` value which will contain `bmi_code` key and date keys for each `bmi_code` like

```
[bmi_code_value] => [[bmi_code => bmi_code_value, date1 => qty1, date2 => qty2, date3 => qty3,//....]]
```

We will also collect the headers (distinct dates)

```
$pivotData = [];
$headers = ['BMI'];
foreach($productionResults as $key => $productionResult){
    if( !isset($pivotData[$productionResult['bmi_code']]) ){
        $pivotData[$productionResult['bmi_code']] = array();
        $pivotData[$productionResult['bmi_code']]['bmi_code'] = $productionResult['bmi_code'];
    }
    $pivotData[$productionResult['bmi_code']][$productionResult['date']] = $productionResult['qty'];
    
    if (!in_array($productionResult['date'], $headers)) {
        $headers[] = $productionResult['date'];
    }
}
```

Now we will loop through our data to show final result set

```
echo join($headers, '  ');
echo '<br>';

foreach($pivotData as $data){
  foreach($headers as $header){
   echo $data[$header]. '  ';
  }
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Output

```
BMI         2020-08-12 2020-08-13 2020-08-14
TA23D7GANV6 2198.27    650.74     424.944
TA40Y3LANC2 394.98     626.52     626.52
```

Comment: hi thank you its working, but how to if i want only value without header

Comment: @FahrulRizal If you don't need `$headers` just skip `echo join($headers, '  ');` this part, but to show values from final collection still need `$headers` array